# Can you change the variable an optionmenu writes to in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Say i have the following optionmenu:

```
   self.cart = StringVar(self.frame1)    
   self.cart.set("")
   self.e1 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.cart, *watercarts)   
   self.e1.grid(row=1, column=1, stick=E+W)
```

As it is, it will save the selected option to `self.cart`. Is there a way to change that?
I tried:

```
    self.e1.config(variable=self.otherVar)
```

It returns, `TclError: Unknown option "-variable"`.

Comment: Have you tried `textvariable`? You can get a list of the keys in config by printing widget.config()

Comment: Yea, i realized that was the issue. Thanks